# Как сделать, чтобы после загрузки файла через Uploadify показывался URL файла?

Tags: php

Тут я и гуглил, находил такой же вопрос, как и мой, и смотрел исходник, пытался что-то своё добавить, но ничего не срабатывало, хоть и в скрипте есть такой комментарий:

```
'onComplete'    : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data){ // Срабатывает когда файл загружен на сервер. По умолчанию файл удаляется из очереди, но мы можем и добваить свои какие-либо действия
```

Вот я и пытался добавить свои действия, но они не срабатывали, ну, например:

```
$link = $files_dir.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Ваша ссылка</a>';
```

Ну, ближе к делу:

Исходник index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Uploadify Демо</title>
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--<script src="//saksmart.ru/razdeli/download/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'scripts/uploadify.swf', // Относительный путь к файлу uploadify.swf. По умолчанию uploadify.swf
        'script'         : 'scripts/uploadify.php', // Относительный путь uploadify.php. По умолчанию uploadify.php. Это скрипт - загрузчик. Обязательно посмотрите его
        'cancelImg'      : 'scripts/cancel.png', // Относительный путь до картинки cancel.png. По умолчанию cancel.png
        'folder'         : 'uploads', // Путь к папке, в которой Вы хотите сохранять загружаемые файлы. 
                                      //Эту настройку можно опустить, тогда папку загрузки необходимо определить в uploadify.php
                                      //Помните! На большистве хостингов, папка, в которую Вы пытаетесь загрузить файлы должна быть доступна на запись, не забудьте выставить соответствующие права 
        'queueID'        : 'fileQueue', // ID элемента, в котором будет показываться очередь загрузки
        'queueSizeLimit' : '30', // Лимит очереди (максим. число загруж файлов). По умолчанию 999
        'auto'           : true, // Если истина, загрузка начнется сразу после выбора файлов
        'multi'          : true,  // Если истина, то разрешена загрузка нескольких файлов
        'fileDesc'       : '*.7z; *.exe; *.rar; *.jpg; *.avi; *.MOV; *.mp4; *.MPG'  , // Текст, который будет внизу появляющегося диалогового окна. Без этого параметра будет написано "Все файлы('.')"
        'fileExt'        : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.JPG; *.7z; *.JPE; *.jpe; *.7z; *.exe; *.rar; *.jpg; *.avi; *.MOV; *.mov; *.mp4; *.MPG; *.flv; *.mkv; *.txt', // разрешенные к загрузке файлы (остальные в диалолговом окне будути скрыты)
        'sizeLimit'      : 1567033999, // Макс. Размер файла для каждой загрузки (в байтах). Если не указываем, ограничено будет только настройками Вашего сервера
        'simUploadLimit' : 2, // Ограничение на кол-во одновременных закачек. По умолчанию 1. Если значение равно 1, то загружаться будет 1 файл, а остальные будут стоять за ним в очереди. Если 2 - два загружаются, остальные ждут их  и т.д
        'buttonText'     : 'File', // Текст на кнопке. По умолчанию BROWSE. К сожалению русскийтекст не поддрживается
        'buttonImg'      : 'scripts/btn.png', // Путь до картинки, которая будет служить кнопкой. Компенсирует недостаток предыдущей. Если эта настройка указана, предыдущая будет проигнорирована
      'width' : 255,
      'height' : 87,
      // 'onInit'        : alert('Скрипт готов!'),// Функция, которая срабатывает, когда скрипт будет загружен. По умолчанию обработчик событий скрывает целевой элемент на странице и заменяет его с флэш-файл, затем создает очереди контейнера после него.
        /*
        'onSelect'       : function(event, queueID, fileObj){ // Функция, которая сработает, при выборе каждого файла. Пример:
                            var string =  'Имя фала: '     + fileObj.name  +'\n';
                                string += 'Размер файла: ' + fileObj.size  + 'байт\n';
                                string += 'Тип: '          + fileObj.type  + '\n';  
                                string += 'ID в очереди: ' + queueID       +'\n'; // уникальный ID файла, генерируется скриптом
                            alert(string)
                         },
        'onSelectOnce'  : function(event, data){   //Функция, которая вызывается один раз для каждой операции выбора.
                            var string  = 'Файлов в очереди: '                  + data.fileCount      +'\n';
                                string += 'Было выбрано файлов: '               + data.filesSelected  +'\n';
                                string += 'Заменено файлов в очереди: '         + data.filesReplaced  +'\n';
                                string += 'Итоговый вес файлов в очереди: '    + data.allBytesTotal  +'\n';
                            alert(string); 
        },
        */
        'onProgress'    : function(event, queueID, fileObj, data){  // Срабатываети каждый раз в ходе изменений во време загрузки
                          var string   = 'ЗАГРУЖАЕМ ЭТО : '                        + fileObj.name            +'<br />';
                              string  += 'Размер: '                                + fileObj.size            +'<br />';
                              string  += 'Тип: '                                   + fileObj.type            +'<br />';
                              string  += 'загрузка текущего файла: '               + data.percentage         +'%<br />';
                              string  += 'загружено байт текущего файла: '         + data.bytesLoaded        +'<br />';
                              string  += 'загружено байт всей очереди: '           + data.allBytesLoaded     +'<br />';
                              string  += 'скорость загрузки, KB/s: '               + data.speed              +'<br />';

                              $('#info,#info2').show();
                              $('#info').html(string);
        },

        'onComplete'    : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data){ // Срабатывает когда файл загружен на сервер. По умолчанию файл удаляется из очереди, но мы можем и добваить свои какие-либо действия
                          var string   = 'Загружен файл сюда : '                   + fileObj.name            +'<br />';
                              string  += 'Путь до файла наверно: '                 + fileObj.filePath        +'<br />';
                              string  += 'Размер, байт: '                          + fileObj.size            +'<br />';
                              string  += 'Тип: '                                   + fileObj.type            +'<br />';
                              string  += 'Пришел ответ от сервера: '               + response                +'<br />';
                              string  += 'Файлов в очереди: '                      + data.fileCount          +'<br />';
                              string  += 'скорость примерной загрузки, KB/s: '     + data.speed              +'<br />';

                              $('#info2').append('<br />Фаил ' + fileObj.name + ' загружен НЕ ТО СЛОВО!<br />');

       },
        'onAllComplete' : function(event, data){ // Срабатывает когда все загрузки завершены
                          var string   = 'Загружено файлов столько: '                      + data.filesUploaded       +'\n';
                              string  += 'Ошибок столько: '                                + data.errors              +'\n';
                              string  += 'Всего загружено kбайт вот: '                     + data.allBytesLoaded/1024 +'\n';

$('#info,#info2').fadeOut(20000, function() { $('#info,#info2').html('');}); // Плавно прячем информационные блоки и затем очищаем их           
        }

    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="DOWNLOAD">

    <h1><strong>Загрузка файлов </strong></h1>
  <div id="fileQueue"></div>
    <input type="file" name="uploadify" id="uploadify" />
  <div id="info"></div>
    <div id="info2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Исходник uploadify.php

```
<?php
/*
Конкретный скрипт загрузки файлов .
*/

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

    if(!$_REQUEST[folder]) $folder = '../uploads/'; // Если в js-части мы не определили директорию загрузки, мы можем сделать это здесь
    else $folder = $_REQUEST['folder'];

    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/';
    $ext = preg_replace('/(?:.*)(\.{1}[a-zA-Z]{3,4})$/','$1', $_FILES['Filedata']['name']); // определяем расширение загружаемого файла
    $unic_name  = time().'_'.rand(0,1000).$ext;
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $unic_name;
```

Если с пониманием относиться к данному вопросу, то правильней было выложить не только исходник, но и файл, вот [ссылка](http://saksmart.ru/skript.7z).

Если у кого-то экспериментально получилось заставить скрипт выводить ссылку на файл, прошу архивировать скрипт и залить через старую версию скрипта на моём [сайте](http://saksmart.ru/razdeli/download/index.php). 
После этого авторы, помогшие редактировать скрипт, будут указаны на сайте не раньше 20 апреля...

Спасибо за внимание, буду рад конкретному ответу на мой вопрос.

Comment: Событие uploadify

onUploadSuccess : function(file, data, response) {
                           
                        },

А в самом php файле, который отвечает за сохранение на сервере нужно вывести 
    echo json_encode(array("file"=>$filename,));//где $filename путь к файлу

Comment: Это событие, да: `$("#uploadify").uploadify({`??? А то, что отвечает за сохранение, - это `uploadify.php`, да? Так переспрашиваю, чтобы ничего не попутать. Можешь описать чуть подробней, как это всё...

Comment:     за сохранение отвечает uploadify.php
    $("#uploadify").uploadify({ 
       ...
       'script' : 'scripts/uploadify.php', //В этом файле сохранение происходит
       onUploadSuccess : function(file, data, response) {
          ...
       },
       ...
    });

Comment: А 

Событие uploadify у нас в index.php? . Твоя наводка чуть-чуть понятна только пока не всё в голове встало на свои места. Значит форма которая приготовляет событие onUploadSucces находиться в index.php  и потом редактируем uploadify.php да?

Comment: да, все верно

Comment: Что-то не выходит в index.php делаю это: 
<code>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#uploadify").uploadify({
  'uploader'       : 'scripts/uploadify.swf', // Относительный путь к файлу uploadify.swf. По умолчанию uploadify.swf
  'script'         : 'scripts/uploadify.php', // 
  onUploadSuccess : function(file, data, response) {

                    }, </code> 

А uploadify.php делаю это - <code> $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $unic_name;
 json_encode(array("file"=>$filename,));//где $filename путь к файлу </code> 

Вставил, как всё сказали, ссылка на файл не появляется.

Answer (score -1):

Из документации:

> onUploadSuccess
>
> data The data that was returned by the server-side script (anything
>   that was echoed by the file)

```
cat uploadify.php
```

```
echo "$furl";
```

cat index.php

`'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response){
$('#progress').html('The file ' + file.name + ' successfully uploaded.');
var smurl = data;
var smurln = window.open(smurl,'_blank');
},`